# Delete duplicate records from a table only if the count is greater than 3

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table as follows:

### A|B|C

1|2|3

1|2|3

1|2|3

1|2|3

1|2|3

4|5|6

4|5|6

4|5|6

4|5|6

7|8|9

7|8|9

7|8|9

I want to remove the duplicates and retain only one value for the record which appear more than 3 times. It should be like:

### A|B|C

1|2|3

4|5|6

7|8|9

7|8|9

7|8|9

I have the following code:

```
DELETE FROM test5 X
WHERE x.ROWID > ANY
  (SELECT Y.ROWID
    FROM test5 Y
    WHERE
      X.A = Y.A
     AND
      X.B = Y.B
    AND
      X.C = Y.C
    );
```

How can I keep only one duplicate of first two tuples(123 and 456) and retain all duplicates of third tuple?

Comment: I think this was answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175281/sql-query-delete-duplicates-if-more-than-3-dups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, why not restrict the deletion to those rows with the desired values using subquery. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM test5 x
WHERE x.ROWID >
ANY( select y.ROWID
FROM test5 y
WHERE X.AA = Y.AA
    AND
      X.BB = Y.BB
    AND
      X.CC = Y.CC)
AND (X.AA, X.BB, X.CC) IN (
SELECT AA, BB, CC FROM TEST5
GROUP BY AA, BB, CC
HAVING COUNT(AA) > 3);
```

This should delete duplicates of the first two tuples only.

Comment: What you are suggesting has no effect on the output whatsoever. Please read the question properly.

Comment: @user3803989 The updated answer is a generic script deletes all duplicated if there are more than 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement deletes all rows occuring more than three times in your table (except the oldest row).

```
delete test5 where rowid in (
  with data as(
  select a,b,c, min(rowid) keep_rowid
  from test5 
  group by a,b,c
  having count(*) > 3)
  select t.rowid from test5 t, data d
  where t.a = d.a
  and t.b = d.b
  and t.c = d.c
  and t.rowid <> d.keep_rowid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
delete test5
 where rowid not in (select rowss
                       from (select A, count(*) counts, min(rowid) rowss
                               from test5
                              group by A
                             having count(*) > 3))--keep one row which's count bigger then 3 (like 1|2|3,4|5|6)
   and A not in(select A from test5 group by A having count(*) <= 3)--keep rows which's counts smaller and equal then 3 (like 7|8|9)
```

table and column names should be wrong sorry.