# How to return a list of numbers that occur more than 200 times in a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with a bunch of columns, the important one being "A".  In column A, I have multiple duplicate entries.  I would like to return only entries which show up in the column 200 times or more.  Is that possible?  I have spent a few hours on it and haven't got anywhere.  I am very new to SQL so I apologize if this is the easiest thing in the world.

Comment: ' I have spent a few hours on it and haven't got anywhere' ...impressive !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query - Delete duplicates if more than 3 dups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175281/sql-query-delete-duplicates-if-more-than-3-dups)

Comment: duplicate questions about duplicates are so meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Having clause. It should give you what you're looking for.

```
Something like this:

    Select ColumnA
    From YourTable
    Group By ColumnA
    Having Count(*) >= 200
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [A], COUNT([A])
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [A]
HAVING COUNT([A]) >= 200
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do using cte

With cte
As
(
Select * ,row_number() over(order by column name) as Id from table name
)
Select * from cte
Where Id > 200