# Delete Duplicate records based on one column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to delete all rows where you have same `Supp-ID, Cust-ID, Order1_Date, Order2_Date, Name` BUT different `Type.`

Only when we have 2 records with Type-1 and Type-2 for the Type column, we need to delete one of these records.

I need help writing this query.

Thanks in advance.

```
Supp-ID Cust-ID Order1_Date Order2_Date Order3_Date Order4_Date Name    Type
00001   001     3/30/2011   4/6/2011    3/30/2011   4/6/2011    John    Type-1
00001   001     3/30/2011   4/6/2011    4/3/2011    4/6/2011    John    Type-2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175061/delete-records-which-are-considered-duplicates-based-on-same-value-on-a-column-a?rq=1

Comment: I think he wants, to delete all if it's different types, and delete one when it's the same type on 2 duplicates.

Comment: I think `Goat CO`  might be correct.  It's hard to tell.  If correct, which one gets deleted?

Comment: Actually there are only two values for Type, Type-1 and Type-2. I would like to delete one row, doesn't matter what the value in type is

Comment: Does your table have a unique key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1175095/122139 deals with a similar situation; yours is simpler, I think, and a simpler version of that answer will hopefully work for you.

Comment: No, I have a composite key. It's a combination of Supp-ID, Cust-ID, Order1_Date, Order2_Date, Name.

Comment: It would be of great help to me if someone can actually post the query considering the data I have provided above..Thanks!